# Accounting for leap years when averaging days into their respective weeks

Tags: r, raster, leap-year

I am working on a project that follows temperature data through time. I have generated raster maps for each day over 40 years. I then want to take the weekly average and generate a .png, to finally generate a GIF to visualise the data for each year. The code I use works fine for regular years, but runs into trouble when it is a leap year.

Here is the code:

```
    dseq <- seq(from = as.Date("01-01-1993", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), to = as.Date("31-12-1993", 
    format = "%d-%m-%Y"), by = 1)
    hdu.fname <- paste("chdu", format(dseq, format = "%Y%m%d"), ".tif", sep = "")
    img.fname <- paste("chdu_week_", 1:52, ".png", sep = "")
    tif.fname <- paste("chdu_week_", 1:52, ".tif", sep = "")

    wid <- c(rep(1:52, each = 7), 52)
    ofile <- data.frame(wid, hdu = hdu.fname)

    for(i in 1:52){
      id <- ofile$wid == i
      tofile <- ofile[id,]
  
      tStack <- stack()
      for(j in 1:length(tofile$hdu)){
         traster <- raster(as.character(tofile$hdu[j]))
         tStack <- stack(tStack, traster)
   }
 
      tchdu.r <- calc(tStack, mean)

      writeRaster(x = tchdu.r, filename = as.character(tif.fname[i]), overwrite = TRUE , format = "GTiff")
  
      breaks <- seq(from = 0, to = 800, by = 100)
      cols <- terrain.colors(n = length(breaks) - 1, alpha = 1)
      sdate <- as.character(tofile[1,2])
  
      sdate <- substr(sdate, start = 5, stop = 12)
      sdate <- as.Date(sdate, format = "%Y%m%d")
      sdate <- format(sdate, format = "%d-%b-%Y")

      windows(); plot(x = aupoly.ext[1:2], y = aupoly.ext[3:4], type = "n", xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude")
      image(tchdu.r, col = cols, breaks = breaks, add = TRUE, zlim = c(0,1000))
      plot(auadm0ll.sf, add = TRUE, colour="transparent", border="#696969")
      contour(tchdu.r, levels = 130, lty = 1, add = TRUE, lwd=1.5, col="purple", drawlabels=TRUE)
      text(x = aupoly.ext[1] + 4, y = aupoly.ext[3] + 2, labels = sdate)
      metre(xl = aupoly.ext[1], yb = aupoly.ext[3] + 24, xr = aupoly.ext[1] + 1, yt = aupoly.ext[3] + 33, lab = breaks, cols = cols, shift = 0, cex = 0.80)
      savePlot(filename = img.fname[i], type = c("png"), device = dev.cur())
      dev.off()
  
      cat(i, "\n"); flush.console()
}
```

When I change the year to a leap year, say 1992, the length of vector dseq is 366, and the length of vector wid is 365. As such, I cannot create the data.frame ofile and run the looping code. The error is:
Error in data.frame(wid, hdu = hdu.fname) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 365, 366

Thanks in advance

Any way around this?

Comment: I don't know which language this is but you'll get more views and responses if you add the appropriate language tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out:

just need to subset the hdu.fname vector with 1 less element